# How to trim and clip both the movie file and the poster file in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, multimedia, includegraphics

I am using this code with the multimedia package:

```
            \movie[label=tetrisMoviePlayer,borderwidth=2pt]%
            {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, trim = 100mm 0 30mm 0, clip]%
                {../zMovFiles/Invertris/posterimage_invertris}}
                {../zMovFiles/Invertris/invertris_trim.mov}
```

to insert a movie into a Beamer presentation. The problem is that I want to "trim" the movie as well as trimming the posterimage. I was hoping that I could insert the trim commands that work for "includegraphics" into the preamble for "movie." BUT when I modify the above code to add the "trim" commands inside the brackets (i.e., []) for the movie, nothing happens, and my error message tells me that both "trim" and "clip" are undefined for multimedia families.

The poster image is beautiful but the movie itself is squished horizontally.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I would rather look into some tools for video editing and modify the video source.

Comment: see for example https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-can-i-crop-a-video-with-ffmpeg and https://askubuntu.com/questions/598324/convert-a-video-to-a-fixed-screen-size-by-cropping-and-resizing